# XML schema pattern exists?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XML and trying to create a schema.
I would like to restrict the name of an element to be
like something Computer Science  for example starting with 
uppercase letter and continue with lowercase. I have tried 
the code below but the validator gives error.I would like 
to store only names with the same format. Any suggestions 
please?

```
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value = "[A-Z][a-z]+"/>
                <xs:whiteSpace value = "collapse"/>
            </xs:restriction>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the design assumption in XML Schema is that you know the element names that are allowed to appear in your source document, and you want to define constraints on their content. You can use wildcards to allow any element name, but there aren't any built-in mechanisms to allow any element name provided it meets specified constraints. You could try and do this with XSD 1.1 assertions, or with Schematron, but you're really running against the grain trying to do this.

You would probably be better off with a design that uses

```
<Subject name="ComputerScience"/>
```

rather than

```
<ComputerScience/>
```

and then it becomes easy to restrict the content of the name attribute with a pattern facet.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice. I have another issue . I want to allow only names that have the letter uppercase and then n number of lowercase. I use this regex  https://regex101.com/r/pT7vR9/3 which works fine but the validator gives me error . The xml element I have is <empFname> Mark </empFname> and this is the code in the schema 

     <xs:element name = "empFname" maxOccurs="1">
   <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
     <xs:pattern value = "^[A-Z][a-z]+"/>
     <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>

Comment: Regular expressions in XSD are implicitly anchored, so you don't need the "^". (And if something "gives me error", then share the information - we need to know what the error is!)

Comment: Incidentally there are numerous people whose first names do not match your proposed pattern, such as my colleague whose first name is O'Neil. What exactly is your purpose in imposing such constraints?